# Eclipse is opening files in the "Problems, Console, History..." View

Tags: eclipse-rcp

For a while now, my Eclipse (Version 2022-12) has started opening Editor Sessions in the View that was, until recently, reserved for Problems, the Console, git History etc.

How can I get it to stop doing this?

Here's a Screenshot, with a couple of extraneous files.

[image]

Comment: A quick Window->Perspective->Reset Perspective menu action will likely restore normal behavior. It's possible you dropped an editor tab into that view stack at some point without realizing it.

Comment: Thanks @nitind that seems to have fixed it. This has been driving me nuts for a couple of months!